# Preprocessing data for the learning step

Tags: reinforcement-learning, algorithms, data-preprocessing, q-learning

I am currently reading "Human level control through deep reinforcement learning" and I came across the algorithm in the paper. I am confused because the algorithm uses a different notation or I must be missing something.

In the paper under *Algorithm 1: deep Q-learning with experience replay.*, it says

> Store transition $(\phi_t, a_t, r_t, \phi_{t+1})$ in $D$

$\phi_{t+1} = \phi(s_{t+1}) = \phi(s_t, a_t, x_{t+1})$ where $x_{t+1}$ is the image (frame which is returned by the gym). So... $a_t$ is not only used in the preprocessing but also in saving in the buffer.

So this algorithm actually says:

> Store transition $(\phi(s_{t-1}, a_{t-1}, x_{t}), a_t, r_t, \phi(s_t, a_t, x_{t+1}))$ in $D$

Why use it in the preprocessing though. Isn't the preprocessing only used for the frame/image?

[edit] A fellow student has pointed out that the preprocessing is used for frames only, as described in

> The function $w$ from algorithm 1 described below applies this preprocessing to the $m$ most recent frames and stacks them to produce the input to the Q-function, in which $m = 4$, although the algorithm is robust to different values of $m$ (for example, $3$ or $5$).

This is still confusing because of the notation of $s_{t+1} = s_t, a_t, x_{t+1}$

Link to the paper: http://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/MnihEtAlHassibis15NatureControlDeepRL.pdf